# Generalizar suma de columnas con Mutate para frames de distintas dimensiones

Tags: r, r-dplyr

Estoy haciendo un análisis de sentimiento básico con el siguiente código

```r
sentimiento <- prueba_tokens %>% 
  anti_join(stop_words, by="word") %>% 
  inner_join(get_sentiments("bing"), by="word") %>% 
  count(sentiment, rowname) %>% 
  spread(sentiment,n,fill = 0) %>% 
  mutate(polaridad=positive-negative)
```

Donde `prueba_tokens`es un tibble con tokens.

El problema radica que cuando cambio de texto, puede que tenga solo palabras positivas o solo negativas, en ese caso el comando `mutate(polaridad=positive-negative)` ya no funciona.

¿Existe una manera de generalizar el `mutate`para casos de un número de columnas variables?

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede resolver con dos ligeros cambios a tu código.

1. Agregar un `mutate()` para cambiar `sentiment` después del `count()`, pasándolo a un factor al que le definimos explícitamente los `levels=`. De ese modo *siempre* habrá positive y y negative, independientemente de los datos.
2. En `spread()` usar el argumento `drop = FALSE` para que siempre haga una columna por nivel (`level`), aunque no esté presente en los datos. De este modo aprovechamos el cambio que hicimos anteriormente.

Así quedaría con tu código:

```
sentimiento <- prueba_tokens %>% 
  anti_join(stop_words, by="word") %>% 
  inner_join(get_sentiments("bing"), by="word") %>% 
  count(sentiment, rowname) %>% 

#Pasamos sentiment a factor con dos niveles explícitos, positive y negative
#De este modo ambas categorías estarán, independientemente de que aparezcan en los datos

  mutate(sentiment = factor(sentiment, levels = c("positive", "negative"))) %>% 

#Agregamos drop = FALSE, para que conserve todos los niveles del factor,
#aunque NO estén presentes
  spread(sentiment, n, fill = 0, drop = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(polaridad=positive-negative)
```

> Seguramente hay otras maneras de hacerlo, esta me gusta porque la solución implica ubicar la información en los datos y mantener las operaciones lógicas simples. Es consiste con la regla de la representación: "Fold knowledge into data so program logic can be stupid and robust."

Comment: Genial @mpaladino ! Acertada tu solución, ha funcionado correctamente. Saludos y gracias!